# How can I use table view cells to edit text just like the settings app does?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As we know, the settings app has some text editing properties in table view cells. I want to know how can we make such cells in our own app using Swift? Thanks!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is create a static grouped table view using storyboard with a text field in each cell.
When I did something like that as approach I decided to switch the input text field delegate in the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method by querying the cell and set the text field as a first responder.
Fortunately I've found that on github, there are some third party lib that makes even easier to create forms. Check [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just decided to use custom cell with a Label and a Text Field (no border) at last :)

[image: My solution]